# 3DSMax: bounding box not fitting the model

Tags: 3ds-max

Bounding box around this imported landscape model is for some reason looking like this:

[image]

How can the model inside the box be rotated so that the bounding box becomes as narrow as the model? Or to put it the other way around: how can the bounding box be resized to fit the model and have as little volume as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Reset XForm, you can find it in [image: Utilities]

or rotate the model perpendicular with the world normal and use Reset XForm and reconvert to poli

Comment: What is meant by phrase «reconvert to poli»? I used XForm to rotate the model, which does result in a normal bounding box now. However, as XForm is a filter, the box returns to the wasteful form if XForm is turned off. Any way to make this change permanent?

Comment: You must convert the object to editable poly (right click on object) with XForm turned on and the bounding box will remain

Comment: This is outstanding, thanks a lot! So the order is the following: **rotate the model as needed** → **reset XForm** → **convert to polygons**. This way the results of XForm are permamentized, while the filter itself (and the orange box representing the old position) is removed. Accepting your answer! 